# Can't start docker, Fatal Error: mkdir /Users/username: permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I had to change my username and home dir , after changing,upon startup I am still receiving an error and docker daemon fails to start.
Docker tries to use the old home directory and has a fatal error resulting in the app crashing

Docker uses the correct home directory and starts after a clean install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution ,
I changed the dataFolder in the `~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json` file to the new user name and start Docker Desktop again.